# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x{2}) was found in the value of attribute "{1}" and element is "0"

Tags: java, xml, unicode, xerces

I have a Base64 encoded string value in the 'attribute' of an XMLTag.

I am using Xerces 2.6.2 ( the one that is bundled with my JDK 1.6) to parse the xml.

I consistently see this exception. 
I tried to use this to 'strip off invalid characters' using http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/02/invalid-xml-characters-when-valid-utf8_5873.html

The xml is of this form -

```
<Name type="type1" value="<base64 encoded string>"/>
```

I still get the exception.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x{2}) was found in the value of attribute "{1}" and element is "0".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:980)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1547)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1320)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
```

I could potentially use a different library but that would entail a code change in production. 
And also I am really really curious why this happens :/

Appreciate any thoughts on this. TIA

Comment: This seems to be an invalid character in the XML file itself. A valid XML file is not allowed to contain control characters such as U+0002. But you won't see them when you look at the text, since sich characters are not actual printable characters.

Comment: @Chronio - Actually, if I just specify random 'text' instead of the base64 string, then, I do not get this exception.

Comment: Then it probably means that whatever is used to perform the base64 encoding inserts an invalid character somewhere in the base64 encoded string.